# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Plugins - Concurrent updates

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, concurrentmodification

I have a custom entity which has near real-time updates (approx 1000 updates per minute). Since the same entity record could get updated in different batch update requests and the requests are received from different async sources, there are chances that a more recent update in the CDS could get overwritten by a slightly older update.

1. Update-1 (with custom attribute datamodifiedon set to 8.02 PM) for Entity record A is processed by async service S1.
2. Update-2 (with custom attribute  datamodifiedon set to 8.03 PM) for Entity record A is processed by async service S2.

Due to network latency or some other reason, S1 service is slightly slow and service S2 went ahead and fired its update call for Entity record A with datamodifiedon 8.03 PM.

Service-1 now fires Update-1 on the same entity record and the update happened at 8.03PM gets overwritten by update happened at 8.02PM leading to data loss.

I have registered a plugin for my custom entity's Update SDK message at Stage 10(Pre-Validation).
This plugin compares datamodifiedon attribute from input parameters with the one set in pre-entity images from plugin context.
And throws Invalid Plugin Execution exception if the pre-entity image already has more recent datamodifiedon attribute.

```
// If ModifiedOn value in pre-image is later than the one received in input parameters, this is an obsolete request and must be rejected.
if (preImage.Contains("datamodifiedon")
    && preImage.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("datamodifiedon") != DateTime.MinValue
    && entity.Contains("datamodifiedon")
    && entity.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("datamodifiedon") != DateTime.MinValue
    )
{
    if (DateTime.Compare(preImage.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("datamodifiedon"), entity.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("datamodifiedon")) > 0)
    {
        string traceMessage = "PreOperationLiveWorkItemUpdatePlugin: Update request is obsolete. datamodifiedon field found in pre-entity image: "
            + preImage.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("datamodifiedon")
            + "datamodifiedon field in Input parameters: "
            + entity.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("datamodifiedon");

        tracingService.Trace(traceMessage);
        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(traceMessage);
    }
}
```

Since the updates happen very frequently, is there a possibility that
1. Update-2 (datamodifiedon 8.03 PM) is in pre-validation stage. Post successful validation, actual update in database is in progress.
2. Now Update-1 enters pre-validation stage. Since Update-2 is not yet committed in the database, will the pre-entity image received in this stage be the old value still and lets the validation to go through?

Would registering this plugin at Pre-Operation or Post-Operation stage help instead of Pre-Validation stage since the other two stages execute in the same database transaction?

Is there any other way to solve this concurrency problem? Since the update is initiated via a batch odata call, eTag pre-condition cannot be used in the request header.

Answer (score 0):

You want to register this plugin on the pre-operation step. I think you have a valid concern regarding the pre-entity image potentially being dirty (I am uncertain whether the pre-image is retrieved within the transaction), so instead of using the pre-image retrieve a fresh copy of the record and check the timestamp of the retrieved record against the timestamp on your target. Since all of your operations are synchronous transactions against the same table, and the timestamp is a field on that table, I think that this will guarantee that you have no dirty writes.

**However:**
If your Update1 and Update2 operations update different fields, now you may suffer the reverse data loss. If Update1 sets Field A and update2 sets Field B, then the change made 
 to field A would be disregarded if it is processed after the update to Field B.

Comment: Thanks for the response. dataupdatedon field would be available in the target entity in every update request being made. So, we are good from that side. My only concern here is : If the plugin gets executed parallelly for both the updates, pre-entity image will not do a dirty read of other updates' transactional data. Pre-entity image will resemble the already committed record in the database. If Update2 gets committed to CDS DB just after Update1's validation in pre-operation step succeeds, will Update1 still go ahead and overwrite?

Comment: I think you have a valid concern regarding the pre-entity image potentially being dirty and I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Given that we have real-time data updates happening, I am afraid if this additional retrieve call will cause more delay and perf impact on the number of records updated per minute.
With the available choices, which stage would you recommend registering the plugin at?
Pre-Validation(10) or Pre-Operation(20) or Post-Operation(30)
Will any of these stages provide additional advantage over the others?

Comment: You need this to happen on pre-operation so that it is part of the update transaction. This does entail a small additional read during every write operation, however the Optimistic Concurrency that Arun suggests (which looks cool) presumably also entails additional read operations under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use [Optimistic concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/optimistic-concurrency). If you can check the row version before updating it.

> The optimistic concurrency feature provides the ability for your applications to detect whether an entity record has changed on the server in the time between when your application retrieved the record and when it tries to update or delete that record.

[Code example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/org-service/entity-operations-update-delete#optimistic-concurrency-behavior)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do I need to explicitly retrieve the record in my pre-validation/pre-operation plugin? Will this delay the updates further or have a perf impact on the number of records that could be updated in a minute?

Comment: You should be retrieving it from the source that is updating it, so it knows what to do if it fails.  Then you wouldn't even need a plugin to handle concurrency.